# How to connect the ESP8266 Wifi Module to firebase through the STM32CubeIDE

Tags: firebase, stm32, esp8266, esp8266wifi, stm32cubeide

I am working on an embedded project on the STM32F103rb Nucleo-64 board.

The project contains the ESP8266 Wifi Module.
I write the code in the STM32CubeIDE workspace.

Is there a way to connect the ESP8266 Wifi Module to firebase through the STM32CubeIDE work environment?
Or is it not possible?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is unclear. You means you want to write and compile ESP8266 code on STM32Cube IDE? That's not possible as the compilers are different. or you means to have ESP8266 as a WiFi shield for STM32 to access the internet? that's totally possible, in fact there are more than one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer @hcheung ! I will clarify the question: I want to create a situation where a motion sensor that detects motion will notify firebase if there has been motion, then the app side (which I write in Angular) will get the update on motion detection from firebase. I know you can link the app side to firebase, but linking the embedded side to firebase still feels like a black hole to me. So: Can the embedded side link to firebase be made using ESP8266? Is it necessary to create a server side or is it not necessary? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

**Update**

The **highlight** text provide clarification as per @ Oz Edri's comment.

Based on your comments. There are two ways to achieve what you want.

1. To have the ESP8266 with [AT Command firmware](https://www.espressif.com/en/support/download/at), and the STM32 communicate with ESP8266 via AT commands to establish an **SSL connection over TCP** with firebase server. In this case, the ESP8266 just acts as a WiFi module.
2. To have the ESP8266 acts as an Arduino, and you design and write your interface protocol and commands between STM32 and ESP8266 (via SPI, I2C or UART). In this case, ESP8266 handle most of the communication while STM32 interfacing with sensors, etc.

I've done both ways in my projects, I have a [blog post](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2020/04/a-better-way-to-use-esp-01-as-wifi-shield/) which might give you some more details on how to implement it.

Comment: Thank you! The information is very helpful, and I will definitely read your blog post!

Comment: In your blog post, in the last paragraph of "Use ESP-01 as a WiFi shield", you wrote "This works well if I only send the request to a web server that does not require SSL". But here in option 1 you wrote "to establish https connection". So it's not clear to me if it's possible or not to connect to Firebase by running AT commands. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: My apology, sorry for misleading information. The AT-Command Set does not support SSL. It has been a while but I remember one of the issues that I was facing was to find the AT commands for supporting HTTPS, which is not available in the AT Command documentation.

Comment: @OzEdri Sorry for misleading you, I just realised that an SSL can be established via an TCP AT Command like `AT+CIPSTART="SSL","url",443`,  you might want to take a look at section 5.2 of the [ESP8266 AT Command Set](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/4a-esp8266_at_instruction_set_en.pdf)

Comment: @hcheung Thank you for your comment. Connecting to Firebase with the AP+CIPSTART="SSL" command is being rejected with an error (the output of that command is "ERROR") and then the connection is being closed (the output is "CLOSED"). SSL connectivity to other sites, including google.com, is possible. Connectivity to Firebase was also possible up to a few weeks ago, probably due to a change in TLS version on their side. Not sure if you still have a working setup to try this and confirm, but if you do, please try and update. Thank you.

Comment: @OzEdri Personally I have not try this yet. Are you using a root-CA or the side cert? Did you read [ESP8266 SSL User Manual](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/5a-esp8266_sdk_ssl_user_manual_en.pdf)? Hope it provide more info.

Comment: @hcheung Thank you for confirming. I'm not using root CA or any cert. Just opening a connection to send more information. With some site, such as google.com, is works. With other, such as firebaseio.com, it doesn't, though it used to - and this is why we're assuming it's due to a change in TLS version on their side. See, AT commands support TLS 1.1, and more and more sites are moving to a newer version of TLS.